# How to separate String of times into parts (array)?

Tags: javascript

I have a String

```
"09:2510:3012:0514:4517:2520:0521:0522:4501:30"
```

I want they can be like this:

[image]

I try to use for , but i still can figure it out.

```
function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < movieTime.length; i++){
        console.log(movieTime[0]);
        // don't know how to complete.

    };
```

Please show me some tips , that would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have a number and you want to change it to an array ?

Comment: Yes , it should be separated like `09:25   10:30  12:05`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With little regex, you can separate them. Assuming you have standard format of string.

```js
var str = "09:2510:3012:0514:4517:2520:0521:0522:4501:30";
var times = str.match(/.{1,5}/g)
console.log(times);
```

Comment: A more precise RE is  `var re = /\d{1,2}:\d{2}/g;`

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var k = 0; k<movieTime.length; k++){
    var seperate=  movieTime.Substring(0,5);
}

for(var i = 0; i < seperate.length; i++){
    console.log(seperate[i]);
}
```

Comment: The loops are slow.  RegEx is better.

Comment: Thanks for your reply , i take another answer.

Comment: @徐博俊 You are welcome, as you wish :) I just want to show you another way :)